# How to connect our callback function to the mosca authenticate method?

Tags: node.js, mqtt, broker, mosca

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var options = {
  username: 'abc',
  password: 'xyz',
}
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt:localhost:1883', options);

function authenteClient() {
      // I need to call this function against the callback at server's 
      // authenticate function.
}
```

In Above code I am providing username and password in options to this mqtt client.

```
var mosca = require('mosca');
var ascoltatore = {
    type: 'mongo',
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mqtt',
    pubsubCollection: 'ascoltatori',
    mongo: {}
    };

var settings = {
  port: 1883,
  backend: ascoltatore 
};
var server = new mosca.Server(settings);
server.on('ready', setup);

function setup() {
  server.authenticate = authenticate;
  console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
}

var authenticate = function(client, username, password, callback) {
   console.log(username, password);
   callback(true);
}
```

Here in server side in the `authenticate` function, I need to connect a callback at client side that is being called there as `callback(true)`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here.

Comment: there is an `authenticate` function at server side that is being called while connecting it. You can see the `callback(true)` in the `authenticate` function. I need to call my function `authenteClient` at client side when the `callback(true)` is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client fails the authentication on the broker side it will not connect.

If it passes it will connect and you can be notified by using the `client.on('connect',function(){})` event listener.

Comment: Yes you are right but if it get failed then how can i get response at client side ?

Answer (score 0):

Late to party but on the client side you can do something like this:

```
//Handle errors
client.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log("Error: ", error.message);
});
```

Any errors from the server can be handled gracefully at this stage.